# why knockout does not auto update by model changes?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

in [parse.com](http://parse.com) I opened up this account `g2840904@trbvm.com/12345678`.
I forked https://github.com/tachang/knockout_tasklist which synchronizes `knockout` to `parse.com` and when i start up the app i do see as the only item `sometitle1` however if I change `sometitle1` to `sometitle2` in [parse.com task class](https://www.parse.com/apps/test--25431/collections) i don't see this being relfected automatically in the webapp.  isn't that what `knockout` supposed to do when the variable [title](https://github.com/avidanyum/knockout_tasklist/blob/master/tasklist.js) is defined as `observabale`?

```
this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
```

What should I do so it does reflect automatically changes in model? meaning changing for example `sometitle1` to `sometitle2` in parse.com would update the web page to reflect that change auotmatically and present `sometitle2` instead of `sometitle1`?

Comment: Knockout defines no way of communication between server and client, nor does it prescribe one. If you want to use Ajax requests, do that. If you want web sockets, do that instead. Whether you use periodic polling with `setInterval`, or background workers, or a pub-sub model is completely up to you. There are libraries for all of those approaches, pick an approach that fits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you misunderstand what KO is supposed to be doing. As a client-side library Knockout takes care to synchronize your UI with the underlying data model, which is provided *by you via `ko.observable` variables*, and not the database itself. There's a reason why apps are broken into 3 tiers - you've got the front-end which handles UI, the middle tier where all business logic resides and the back-end that serves as data storage. Knockout bridges *the middle tier and the front-end*, while you are asking for a direct bridge between the front and back-end.

That being said, you can provide this bridge yourself, but of course writing it from a scratch is somewhat painful exercise. The easiest possible way is to ask the db whether any new data has arrived every X seconds using `setInterval`:

```
var updateTasks = function () {
    $.parse.get("task", {}, function(json) {
        self.tasks.removeAll();
        for( var i = 0; i < json.results.length ; i++ ) {
             var task = json.results[i];
             self.tasks.push(new Task({ title: task.title, objectId: task.objectId }));
         }
     })
 }
 setInterval(updateTasks, 5000);
```